# Why is there a difference between printing escaped hex characters inline in the terminal and in a program running the the terminal?

Tags: python, printing, escaping, pwntools

I was trying to send a string to another application running on a server (which I do not have access to). The string includes null characters.
Now I noticed that when I run the following code in a script,

```py
print('abc\x00\x91\x11\x01123')
```

the output is: abc\x00\x91\x11123.

Athought when I run the same code in the terminal:

`python -c 'print("abc\x00\x91\x11\x01123")'`

I get as output: abc�123

Which is the desired output in my case.
Why do both outputs differ?
How do I get the second output when running the print function in a script?

EDIT:
I figured out what was causing the difference.
pwntools caused that behaviour.
But I still can't really figure out why.
The following code:

```
#!/usr/env/python
import pwn

print('abc\x00\x91\x11\x01123')
```

results in

abc\x00\x91\x11123

When I do not import pwn, the result is as expected:
abc�123.

Comment: I cannot imagine how you could ever get `abc\x00\x91\x11123` as output of `print('abc\x00\x91\x11\x01123')`. That is simply wrong. What exactly did you do to get that output?

Comment: I figured out that it an import caused this behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this qualifies as answer in Stack Overflow standards.

*If you play with grenade, treat is like grenade, not a toy.* [PWN tools](http://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/about.html) seem to be some script-kiddies tools for exploitation. If you would read the first few paragraphs of the documentation, you would find the following:

> As stated, we would also like to have the ability to get a lot of these side-effects by default. That is the purpose of this module. It does the following:
>
> [...]Calls pwnlib.term.init() to put your terminal in raw mode and implements functionality to make it appear like it isn’t.

You have been warned, however you haven't RTFM.

Answer (score 0):

**There is actually no difference.** Your problem is elsewhere but not in the difference of interpretation between in a terminal and in a script.

Here is the output I have locally for your example:

```
[cecile@CC-PC ~]$ python
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('abc\x00\x91\x11\x01123')
abc_123
>>>
[cecile@CC-PC ~]$ python -c 'print("abc\x00\x91\x11\x01123")'
abc_123
```

On this machine the non-printable characters seems to be replaced by `_` but the point here is that, as you can see, the result is the same in the interpreter and in the terminal.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. It only says that the question is invalid. Such comments belong in the _comments_ section, not in the answers.

Comment: It's easier to demonstrate in the answer with proper code identation than in a comment. Besides I can always update it later when there is more input.

Comment: I figured out that it an import caused this behaviour. This is weird. How could an import alter the print function. The import such as I descripted it in the EDIT part is not supposed to change anything is it?

Comment: I have no idea. This is the first time I see this but it's good that you found it :) Check the doc, maybe there is info about it